# how to optimize union in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I read that it's better to sort on the database side rather than loading it all into memory, but I feel like a lot could be done to improve this. I am just using union to order the various queries. is this a bad approach and should I do something to optimize the query?

I have heard that premature optimization is the root of all evil, but I would like to improve my knowledge of sql

```
select 1 as seq, t.* from template t
join template_type_link ttl on ttl.template_idx = t.idx 
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'  
and
t.title in all(array['happy', 'birthday']) 
UNION
select 2 as seq, t.* from template t
join template_type_link ttl on ttl.template_idx = t.idx 
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'  
and
t.title ~~* any(array['%happy%', '%birthday%']) 
UNION
select 3 as seq, t.*  from template t 
join template_type_link ttl on ttl.template_idx = t.idx 
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'  
and
t.idx in (select template_idx from template_keyword where keyword in ('happy', 'birthday' ))      
order by seq asc
```

Comment: For starters, use `union all` instead of `union` to avoid the costly removal of duplicates that can't happen with your query

Comment: The first query is useless I think. Anything returned by the first, will also be included in the second.

Comment: the main thing is I want to sort the stuff from the first query to the top. is there a better way to sort so that an exact match is placed above partial matches using '%happy'%

Comment: You could use something like `... and t.title ~~* any(array['%happy%', '%birthday%'])  order by t.title ~~* all(array['happy', 'birthday']) desc` that would return those with an exact match first

Comment: oh that's cool. I will try that out then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technique will work, except it should be `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.

But if all you want is four result sets in sequence, where the order in each result set doesn't matter, you might be better off by just running the four individual queries one after the other. That will avoid sorting, which can be pretty expensive. This approach may win if there are many result rows.

If there are only few result rows, the cost might be dominated by the number of client-server round trips, and your original approach may win.

Try both and benchmark to see what is better for you.